# Position UISearchBar programmatically using UISearchController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchcontroller

I'm attempting to position my UISearchBar directly under my UINavigationBar but I'm having issues where it's not appearing at all. I'm using iOS8's new searchController.

```
 self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
 self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
 self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);
 self.salesTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

Currently I'm using that which correctly adds it to my UITableView header, but the issue with that is that it scrolls with the table which is not what I want. I want it above my tableview so it sticks instead and tried this but it seems to be gone now, unless I'm not using the right 
 values?

```
 self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
 self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
 self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);
 //  self.salesTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

Answer (score 5):

Because the origin is (0,0), it will be hidden by status bar and navigation bar. You should see the search bar if changing to:

```
self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);
```

I have two solution. I will show you the easy way (you could also use storyboard): Create a UIView in your ViewController, named `searchBarView`; Add `self.searchController.searchBar` into the `searchBarView`; Add `searchBarView` to your ViewController.

```
UIView *searchBarView = CGRectMake(0, 64, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44);
[searchBarView addSubView:self.searchController.searchBar];
[self.view addSubView:searchBarView];
```

I assume that you setup search controller `self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()` in viewDidload. If it is the universal app, you need to add this method (at least in my case to make everything work):

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    // you could check
    // if (IS_IPAD || (IS_IPHONE_6PLUS && UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))) 
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
}
```

This is my first answer on stackoverflow. Hope this help ^^.

Answer (score 2):

Two things to check out:

1. Try setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `false` on your `UIViewController`. That should shift the subviews of your view controller's view to below the navigation bar.
2. Use `searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment` (available iOS 5+) to adjust the position of the search field inside of your `UISearchBar`

---

Usage:

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar()
searchBar.searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 10)
```