# UISplitViewController with new UISearchController issue with UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I recently started to rewrite my iOS app to use the new `UISearchController` and a universal storyboard. 
My app is available for both devices (*iPhone* and *iPad*) so the change to the universal storyboard using the `UISplitViewController` was a big advantage.

But sadly the `UISearchController` isn't working as expected. I added the `UISearchController` with the following lines:

```
self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
self.myTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

My controller chain is like that:

```
UISplitViewController
    UITabbarController (Master)
        UINavigationController
            UITableViewController
    UINavigationController (Detail)
        UINavigationController
            UIViewController
```

The problem is that in the iPad app the `UISearchBar` is covered by the `UINavigationBar`. But if I switch the tabs and go back to the view. The `UISearchBar` is visible. So somehow after a tabbar switch it redraws the view correctly. In the iPhone Version it works automatically correct.

**iPad App**

After the first launch the `UISearchBar` is covered by the `UINavigationBar`

[image: After the first launch the UISearchBar is covered by the UINavigationBar]

After switching the tabs the `UISearchBar` is displayed correctly

[image: After switching the tabs the UISearchBar is displayed correctly]

**iPhone App**

The iPhone app is working correctly without changing the tabs..
[image: iPhone App works as expected]

**What I tried:**

- Using different settings of extendingEdges
- Add the SearchController in the viewWillAppear method because I thought I can trick it by adding the search control later on

Answer (score 0):

I assume you setup search controller `self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()` in viewDidload. Beside that, you need to add this method (Objective-C code):

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    // you could check
    // if (IS_IPAD || (IS_IPHONE_6PLUS && UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))) 
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
}
```

In case it does not work, you could add these codes into your `viewDidlLoad` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
self.yourTableViewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

If you wants to dock your search, please refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639791/position-uisearchbar-programatically-using-uisearchcontroller?answertab=votes#tab-top)