# Using UISearchController with UISearchBar in tableHeaderView in iOS11

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, ios11, uisearchcontroller

Has anyone successfully retained a `UISearchBar` in a `tableHeaderView` of a `UITableView` in ios11? Problems usually arise with iPhone X in landscape:

[image]

Apple recommends using the new `searchController` property:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = NO;
} else {
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
}
```

However this doesn't always work. Here is an example with code:

[iOS11 UISearchBar missing in UINavigationBar when embedded in UISplitViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387166/ios11-uisearchbar-missing-in-uinavigationbar-when-embedded-in-uisplitviewcontrol)

So trying to keep the `searchBar` in `tableHeaderView` - a practical first step is to apply the appropriate auto layout constraints:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    UILayoutGuide *guide = self.tableView.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
    searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [searchBar.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.leftAnchor].active = YES;
    [searchBar.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.rightAnchor].active = YES;
}
```

The `searchBar` is then correctly sized when displayed:

[image]

However the problem arises when the `UISearchBar` is activated:

[image]

This seems to be an old problem. There are numerous stackoverflow questions and answers relating to issues like this. In this case, on inspection of the view hierarchy, it appears the width of the `UISearchBar` is set incorrectly. So this can be corrected:

```
- (void)didPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(11_0)
{
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        CGRect frame = self.searchController.searchBar.frame;
        frame.size.width = [self safeWidthAvailable];
        self.searchController.searchBar.frame = frame;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)safeWidthAvailable
{
    CGRect frame = ((AppDelegate *)MyApplication.sharedApplication.delegate).window.frame;
    CGFloat width = frame.size.width;
     if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
       UIEdgeInsets insets = ((AppDelegate *)MyApplication.sharedApplication.delegate).window.safeAreaInsets;
       width -= insets.left;
       width -= insets.right;
    }
    return width;
}
```

So this works:

[image]

Until you rotate with `UISearchController` active:

[image]

So again `UISearchController` has misplaced `UISearchBar`.

Why is this so hard?

One solution is to save the search, disable `UISearchController` after a rotation, and re-enable it with the saved search. This works, but it shouldn't need to be so complicated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you can consider my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46908553/7848589